# How can I vectorize my custom pytorch conv2d operation?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a backwards pass of a custom conv2d layer that I think can be vectorized.

```py
for s in range(num_samples):
    for c in range(num_channels):
        temp_input = input[s, c, :, :].unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
        temp_doutput = doutput[s, :, :, :].unsqueeze(1)
        temp_conv2d = torch.nn.functional.conv2d(temp_input, temp_doutput, stride=dilation, padding=padding, dilation=stride, groups=groups).squeeze(0).squeeze(0)
        cut_conv2d = temp_conv2d[:, :kernel_size, :kernel_size]
        grad_w[:, c, :, :] += cut_conv2d
```

The reason I think it can be vectorized is that if it wasn't vectorized, with an input of 50000 images of size 512x512, with the current configuration, it would have to perform billions of conv2d functions for just a single epoch. I'm guessing that's not right, but I can't think of a way to vectorise this any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, with vectorizing, the idea is to add any of the iterables as an additional dimension of your vector (using `view`) to utilize broadcasting, and then reshape (`view`) back to your original dimensions.

```
input_reshaped = input.view(num_samples, 1, input.size(1), input.size(2), input.size(3))
doutput_reshaped = doutput.view(num_samples, 1, doutput.size(1), doutput.size(2), doutput.size(3))

temp_conv2d = torch.nn.functional.conv2d(input_reshaped, doutput_reshaped, stride=dilation, padding=padding, dilation=stride, groups=groups).squeeze()

cut_conv2d = temp_conv2d[:, :, :kernel_size, :kernel_size].permute(0, 2, 3, 1)
grad_w += cut_conv2d.sum(dim=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Not sure if it's possible to remove the last for loop, but this already speeds it up 100x for me, so good enough.

```py
for s in range(num_samples):
            temp_input = input[s, :, :, :].unsqueeze(1)
            temp_doutput = doutput[s, :, :, :].unsqueeze(1)
            
            temp_conv2d = torch.nn.functional.conv2d(temp_input, temp_doutput, stride=dilation, padding=padding, dilation=stride, groups=groups).squeeze()
            cut_conv2d = torch.permute((temp_conv2d[:, :, :kernel_size, :kernel_size]), (1, 0, 2, 3))
            grad_w[:, :, :, :] += cut_conv2d
```